# tsconfig.json 's compiler options where do they come from?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, package.json, tsconfig

I'm working with Typescript in NestJs. I have added some packages but I don't know which one made this change
`"checkJs": false,   "skipLibCheck": true`
Is there any way to figure out which one did this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages shouldn't ever be changing your TSConfig.json file. I certainly haven't heard of any doing that.

If you're using Git, you can check the commit history and see at what point that got changed.